# python equivalent of qnorm, qf and qchi2 of R

Tags: python, r, scipy

I need  the quantile of some distributions in python. In r it is possible to compute these values using the qf, qnorm and qchi2 functions.

Is there any python equivalent of these R functions?
I have been looking on scipy but I did non find anything.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You may find probability distributions in [`scipy.stats`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions). Every distribution defines a set of functions, for example if you go to [`norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm) distribution and scroll down the page you may find the methods which include

```
ppf(q, loc=0, scale=1)  # Percent point function (inverse of cdf — percentiles)
```

that is what `scipy` calls Percent *point function* and does what `R` `q` functions does.

For example:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> norm.ppf(.5)  # half of the mass is before zero
0.0
```

Same interface for other distributions, say `chi^2`:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import chi2
>>> chi2.ppf(.8, df=2) # two degress of freedom
3.2188758248682015
```

Comment: so percent point function compute the quantile of a distribution?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the oddly named Percent Point Function in scipy.  Being unfamiliar with scipy, I've spent WAY too much time trying to google around was just about to ask how to do the equivalent of R's `qnorm` in Python when I landed on this page.

Comment: Also want to point out that this is equivalent to Excel's `NORMINV()` function to help future searchers (Googlers).

Answer (score 57):

The equivalent of the R `pnorm()` function is: `scipy.stats.norm.cdf()` with python
The equivalent of the R `qnorm()` function is: `scipy.stats.norm.ppf()` with python

Comment: I think that answer may have aged.  I can't seem to find norm.ppf in the docs, but I did find this: [scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf)

Comment: @EngrStudent Here you can find `norm.ppf` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html