# Quantile functions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, quantile

I'm having trouble finding quantile functions for well-known probability distributions in Python, do they exist?  In particular, is there an inverse normal distribution function?  I couldn't find anything in either Numpy or Scipy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24695174/625914

Comment: ... and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626994/how-to-calculate-the-inverse-of-the-normal-cumulative-distribution-function-in-p/20627638#20627638

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the .ppf() method of any distribution class in scipy.stats. 
This is the equivalent of a quantile function (otherwise named as percent point function or inverse CDF)

An example with the [exponential distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html) from scipy.stats:

```
# analysis libs
import scipy
import numpy as np
# plotting libs
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example with the exponential distribution
c = 0
lamb = 2

# Create a frozen exponential distribution instance with specified parameters
exp_obj = scipy.stats.expon(c,1/float(lamb))

x_in = np.linspace(0,1,200) # 200 numbers in [0,1], input for ppf()
y_out = exp_obj.ppf(x_in)
plt.plot(x_in,y_out) # graphically check the results of the inverse CDF
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems new but I've found [this](http://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) about numpy and quantile. Maybe you can have a look (not tested)

Comment: That gives the empirical quantiles of a set of observations, rather than the exact quantiles of a theoretical distribution the poster is asking for.  It is new to numpy, but gives the same functionality as the function `np.percentile`.